# Dplyr: using mutate , across , where and ìfelse to multiple entire column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my code:

```
library(vcd)
data(Arthritis)

df<-as.tibble(Arthritis)

df %>% mutate(across(where(~ is.integer(.x) && first(.x) > 50), ~ ifelse(is.integer(.x), .x * 2, .x)))
```

I would like multiply the entire column that has as the first row a number above 50 and is an `integer`.

But why its not working?
Probably because Im using `first(.x)`.
What am I doing wrong by using `first`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `first()` logic out of the selection and into the operation, don't duplicate the `is.integer` check:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.integer),
         ~ if(first(.x) > 50) {.x * 2} else{.x})
  )
```

Comment: Many thanks. I still dont understand why this didnt work. ìfelse` shouldnt give me the same output?

Comment: `is.integer(1:3)` will return a single TRUE or FALSE. The `ifelse()` result is always the same length as the `ifelse()` test argument, in this case length 1 because the `is.integer()` result is length 1. (Would have the same issue with `first` - the test is length 1, but the result you want is longer.) So we need to switch to `if(){}else{}`, which always expects test of length 1, and the result can be anything.

Comment: There *might* be a way to do it all with the selection argument of across, but this seems more natural to me: "> 50" won't be meaningful for all column types, so it makes sense to first get the integer columns, then test whether their first entry is > 50.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!